# Allow the user to rotate the map in any direction?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps, cordova

I have a Google-maps page in my application, which is made with Html5 and wrapped in PhoneGap. I want to allow the user to **rotate** the map in any direction, **not just zoom in and out**.  How can I do this?

My preference is to do this in JavaScript, but if that is impossible then I'll do it via Android.

Comment: Did you see the following solution: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4599/how-do-i-rotate-a-google-map ?

Comment: I want to allow it to user to of my application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual question is about custom rotation for Google Maps. I would suggest to use any non-standard solution as a temporary one. There is a good [demo](http://isithackday.com/hacks/map-rotate/), it is based on [jQuery rotate and scale plugin](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html)

[image]